# Comando remove não funcionando ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular, ionic3, navegação

Estou tendo problema com o `navCtrl.push`. O fluxo é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas paginas `1.1, 1.2 e 1.3` posso ir e voltar quantas vezes eu quiser porém quando clicar no botão voltar preciso necessariamente voltar na pagina 1.

Para ir para próxima pagina utilizo o evento `click` do botão assim:

```
(click)="quickAccess('Pagina1.1')"
```

E para voltar adiciono `navPop` ao meu botão do `navbar`.

**O ERRO**

Quando clico em voltar está voltando partes por pastes das paginas `1.2, 1.2 e 1.3` suponhamos se eu naveguei 10 vezes entre estas pastes ele irá voltar as 10 vezes.

**TENTATIVAS**

Estou tentando seguir o seguinte pensamento quando navego por exemplo da pagina `1.1` para `1.2` eu devo remover a `1.1` e assim por diante, porém estou tendo este problema, de como fazer isto, ja tentei fazer por `index` pelo `nome da view` mas nenhuma deles funciona.

**VALE LEMBRAR**

É importante saber que existem outras paginas anteriores a `PAGINA 1` o fluxo com problema é apenas neste caso, nos restante tudo anda conforme o esperado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema !

Segundo esta inssue no ionic team:

```
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12238
```

Está ocorrendo um erro na estrutura, a solução foi a instalação da correção via npm como informado na inssue:

```
npm install ionic-angular@nightly --save
```

Assim meu `.remove()` funciona perfeitamente agora.